# Chat application - Sender gets notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an android chat application, where there are chat rooms users can use to write messages. Inside a chat room they can choose to subscribe to that room. The purpose of this is to receive push notifications when new messages are added to the room.

I've made this functionality with Cloud Functions and Topics. Here is my code:

```
exports.pushNotification = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/{id}').onCreate((change, context) => {
const pushId = context.params.pushId;

const originalText = change.val();

const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: originalText.message,
        body: originalText.sender,
        sound: "default"
    },
};

const options = {
    priority: "high",
    timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
};


return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(pushId, payload, options);

});
```

**Problem**
If a user is subscribed to a topic and sends a message that same user also gets a notification. How can I prevent the user sending the message from getting the notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to suppress sending a message to one token in a topic. You can either send the message to the topic, or not send it to the topic.

What you can do, is suppress displaying the message on the client. For that it is important to understand the different [message types that FCM supports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages):

- **Notificaton messages** are automatically displayed by the system if your app is not active, and delivered to your application code if the app is active.
- **Data messages** are never automatically displayed by the system, and always delivered to your application code.

So to have full control over who *sees* the message, you can use a data message. But in the case of a chat app, you can also consider using a notification message, since the user will often be using the app to send the message when you send the notification. There may be some edge cases there though, so if those are getting in your way: send a data message, and trigger showing the notification from your own application code.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply send hidden `userID` in message using some separator Like below example

```
notification: {
        title: originalText.message+ '____'+userID,
        body: originalText.sender,
        sound: "default"
    }
```

then while you are showing your Notification Bar

get the message and Split it like Below then put message as shown Below

`String message = mMessage.split("____")[0];`

now In notification bar show `message` instead of `mMessage`